# gdalwarp msvcr120.dll problem

Tags: installation, gdalwarp

when I use gdawarp command it was failed - reproject with proj4. It was related with msvcr120.dll.
Surely I was already install  MS VC++2013 redistributable (x64). I was copy dll to gdal folder but same.
I can't find any questions related with msvcr120.dll and gdalwarp in history.
Has anyone encountered this problem?

### windows 7 pro, x64

I was installed 'gdal-201-1800-x64-core'  and I was set system variables GDAL_DATA, GDAL_DRIVER_PATH

My command is:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -co TFW=YES -t_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=127 +k=1 +x_0=200000 +y_0=600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" .\data\a102113.tif .\data\b5186.tif
```